# Angularjs - Simple radio button NOT able select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to show a dynamic list (of file name items) using an html radio button. Please find the code below for the same:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular-v1.5.5.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label>
          <input type="radio" ng-model="inputCreatedBy" value="byX" ng-value="true"
            ng-click="toggleSelection('byX')"> by X&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="radio" ng-model="inputCreatedBy" value="byAll"  ng-value="false"
            ng-click="toggleSelection('byAll')"> by All&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </label>
    <br/><br/>
    <label ng-repeat="file in displayFiles">
            {{ file.name }}
    </label>

</div>
</body>
<script>
   var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
   app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, filterFilter) {
   $scope.files = [
        { name: 'file1', createdBy: 'X' },
        { name: 'file2', createdBy: 'X' },
        { name: 'file3', createdBy: 'Y' },
        { name: 'file4', createdBy: 'Y' }
    ];
    $scope.displayFiles = [];
    $scope.toggleSelection = function(selectionType) {
        if(selectionType == 'byX') {
            for(i=0;i<$scope.files.length;i++) {
                if($scope.files[i].createdBy =='X') {
                    $scope.displayFiles.push($scope.files[i]);
                }
            }
        } else if(selectionType == 'byAll') {
            $scope.displayFiles = $scope.files;
        }
    };
   });
</script>
</html>
```

I am facing the below issues with this code:

(1) The Radio button option 'by X' is not selected by default, even though I marked it with ng-value 'true'.

(2) After selecting 'by All' option, I am NOT able to select 'by X' option.

Could you please help to fix these issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code. Please look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7042/).

There were the following problems with your code:

1. `$scope.inputCreatedBy` should've been set to `byX` to get it selected by default.
2. `$scope.displayFiles` should've been cleared each time `toggleSelection` function was used.
3. [`ngValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) should be used to bind an angular expression to the value attribute of the input element. So the directive is not required in your case.